# Does a local variable stay local if it's reassigned?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have this in a bash function

```
ql_do_x(){
   local foo="bar";
   if true; then
      foo="zam";
   fi
}
```

If I run:

```
foo="unmodified"
ql_do_x
echo "$foo"
```

...is it guaranteed that the outer value of `foo` will be "unmodified", even though the `local` keyword was only used on the first assignment in the function and not the second one?

Comment: It's actually best practice to run `local foo` and then assign it a value later/separately.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think I follow

Comment: Has my answer adequately clarified?

Comment: yeah I thiink so upvote impending

Comment: I assume the answer to the original question is "yes", in any case

Comment: Edited to bold that part of the response. :)

Comment: Huh -- close vote is as "lacking MCVE". I'm editing the question to try to clarify it (at least per my understanding) -- feel free to revert if I'm misrepresenting what you meant to ask in any way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Absolutely, yes.** In fact, it's better if you rely on this, and declare your variables *prior* to their assignment. Consider the following (not-very-unusual) example, where the value being assigned is coming from a command substitution, and where we want to handle the case where that command substitution fails:

```
ql_do_x() {
  local foo
  if ! foo=$(bar); then
    foo=baz
  fi
}
```

If you ran `if ! local foo=$(bar)`, then it would always be true (before the `!`), because you'd be testing the exit status of `local` (which, as a command, has an exit status -- which is always true if the variable name(s) provided are valid), not the command substitution running `bar`.

Comment: maybe I don't understand what `local` is actually doing. I am currently under the impression that local means it will never leave the scope of the function.

Comment: You're correct about that -- `local var1 var2` defines var1 and var2 as function-local. My point, however, is that this declaration itself is a command, and has an exit status, and that you probably don't want it to override the exit status of whatever's generating the values you assign.

Comment: I guess using local means it will not reassign any variables with the same name outside the scope of the function

Comment: that seems to the primary utility of `local` afaict

Comment: Correct. By default, shell is like JavaScript in that all variables are global unless declared otherwise.

Comment: I see, yeah subshells complicate that a bit, because it's not available in subshells unless you export the var, but o/w yeah I guess you are right

Comment: Variables *are* copied to subshells -- as a `fork()` without an `exec()`, a subshell is an exact copy of the parent process, shell variables included. It's only child shells created by `exec()`ing a new interpreter that need an `export`.